# Swift: ¿Como realizo tareas en segundo plano indefinidamente?

Tags: swift, timer, background

Estoy desarrollando una App donde los usuarios registran sus actividades durante la realización de un proyecto, y necesito mandarles una notificación cada cierto tiempo si no han capturado sus actividades, esto implica que la app en segundo plano pueda estar "contando" el tiempo para mandar la notificación, le problema es que no logro que un proceso se quede ejecutando todo el tiempo aun si la app esta en segundo plano o el cel bloqueado.

Esto es lo que he intentado:
En el viewDidLoad() tengo un "observer" para identificar cuando la app es mandada a segundo plano(minimizada) y correr un timer con X intervalo:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (Notification) in
            print("entro en background")
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
                var backTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier(rawValue: 1)
                backTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
                        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backTask)
                    })
                let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(self.sendNotification), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .common)
                RunLoop.current.run()
            }
```

Tengo el intervalo cada 10 segundos solo para probar pero la idea es que solo una vez al día se realice esta comprobación de inactividad para saber si mandar o no la notificación.
Pero con esta forma, una vez que la app pasa a segundo plano o se bloque el cel la operación solo funciona durante 30 segundos y la app pasa a modo suspensión, que necesito hacer para que esta tarea se repita indefinidamente o evitar que la app se suspenda.

Pienso en aplicaciones como Telegram o whatsApp donde sin importar cuanto tiempo lleve el cel bloqueado aun la app nos envía notificaciones de algún mensaje que recibimos, ¿como se logra ese tipo de comportamiento?

Answer (score 1):

No se puede utilizar un timer infinito en background; por eso Apple solo permite 30 segundos.

Lo que puedes hacer es enviar una notificación local después de pasado los 30 segundos que pasa la app del background a un modo inactivo. Entonces haces lo siguiente en el archivo `AppDelegate`:

1. Agregas la notificación:

   ```
   import UserNotifications
   ```
2. Creas una variable global:

   ```
   let notification = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
   ```
3. Agregas el permiso:
   let option: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]

   ```
    notification.requestAuthorization(options: option) { (didAllow, error) in
        if !didAllow {
            print("Autorización de notificaciones rechazada")
        }
    }
   ```
4. Creas la notificación:

   ```
   let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
   content.title = "Alerta de inactividad"
   content.subtitle = "Debes registrar tu actividad"
   content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
   ```
5. Configuras para que la notificación se envíe en `x` segundos. En este caso está `10` segundos:

   ```
   let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10, repeats: false)
   let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "miNotificacion", content: content, trigger: trigger)
   ```
6. En el `observer` al pasar a background agregas la notificación:

   ```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (Notification) in
            print("entró en background")
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
                var backTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier(rawValue: 1)
                backTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
                    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backTask)
                    //Agregas la notificación
                    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
                })
            }
        }
   ```
7. En el caso que la app vuelva a estar activa, eliminas la notificación:

   ```
   func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["miNotificacion"])
    }
   ```

Si ejecutas la app y la pasas a background te aparece el mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al esperar los 30 segundos y los 10 segundos de la notificación te aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:** Los servicios de mensajería trabajan con notificaciones Push que vienen de un servidor externo y trabajan registrando el `UUID()` de cada dispositivo que es un identificador único. Todo se trabaja desde el backend y por eso es que incluso si la app está cerrada completamente te llegan las notificaciones.

Comment: Gracias por responder Bicho, ya había intentado esa forma de programar la notificación, pero no me gustaba la idea de que solo se ejecutara una vez, por eso buscaba mas una forma de proceso repetido, pero bueno si no hay otra manera de hacerlo localmente tendré que conformarme con lo que hay.

Comment: Con `repeats: true` puedes hacer que se vuelva a enviar la notificación infinitamente. Eso si debe ser mayor a `60` segundos.

Comment: ¿Pero con esto solo repito la notificación y no el calculo para saber si enviarla, cierto? Porque antes de enviarla necesito calcular los tiempos inactivos y saber si es necesario enviarla.

Comment: La notificación se va a enviar hasta que el usuario abra de nuevo la app. Es decir si seteas que en 1 hora se envía la notificación, después de otra hora si sigue inactivo se va a enviar la misma notificación. Si abre la app, se elimina las futuras notificaciones y si vuelve a background a partir de ahi se calcula 1 hora para el envío de la notificación nuevamente.

Comment: Es que necesito calcular los tiempos, porque un usuario puede tener varios proyectos activos al mismo tiempo y si solo entra a actualizar uno de ellos, hacerlo de esta manera será muy general, y necesito que si de una hora a otra, algún otro proyecto ya entro en ese periodo de inactividad estipulado, poder notificárselo. Y en lugar de solo ser: "has estado inactivo" decirle: "el proyecto X lleva X tiempo inactivo". Por cierto, gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Entonce deberías analizar la opción de tener un backend al cual vas a enviar la hora a la que abra un proyecto y si está en background. En el backend haces el cálculo de inactividad por proyecto y envías con notificaciones push. Analiza los precios de Azure o Firebase.